# Create very long exposure clouds with brushes or other techniques in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photography

I know how to do long exposure, but sometimes, quite often in fact, the end result does not look as good as I wish, in terms of patterns.

An alternative would be replacing the sky, but I'm asking if it possible to create it from scratch. Assuming I'd like to create those very long exposure textures on the sky (essentially stripes of clouds like [this](http://rebeccajoyce.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/long_exposure_samples-4.jpg)), are there techniques (based on brushes?) to achieve that?

[image]

Essentially I want stripes of clouds like the image above. I searched online, but I could not find anything.

Comment: Hello and welcome your question is unfortunately  too broad to be answered. Perhaps adding a picture showing what you are looking for could help.

Comment: added example...

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a blur effect. A radial blur is probably your best bet.

Take this:

[image]

Add a Radial Blur effect:

[image]

Mask the areas you don't want affected:

[image]

If the radial blur is too mechanical for your liking, you can add some distortion *(Filter → Distort → Wave, Spherize or others)*. The dialog in the screenshot is left to show the effect magnitude.

[image]

Another quick example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: In my case I have images with no clouds on the sky. I guess I can take them from another photo.  However, I was wondering if they can be created from scratch. The reason is that I don't always like how clouds look like and I would like to create those stripes the way I want. Like in the first examples you made, perhaps with brushes?

Comment: Fair enough. A blur like I did is probably still your best bet. You could either just find some clouds that you do like, or brush in roughly what you want and blur that.

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop have this nifty filter called "render>clouds". I use it for creating brushed metal textures and things like that but I think they could render some nice clouds.
But being sarcastic apart. When it come to realistic clouds I advise to use cloud brushes. You can download them from resource sites or create them by yourself (which is much easier). Just make a lot of sky photos with your camera set in a way you will replicate later (so angle, height above the ground, lens etc.) Then separate clouds and make brush from them.

Or just any brush and blur it like in above examples. 
[image: clouds]

Remember, people will see in the picture what you tell them.